# How do I prove that the following method to find whether a point lies within a polygon is correct?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, triangles, determinant

I came across the following method to determine whether a given point lies inside a convex polygon - however, I'm not sure how to prove it.

Given any three points on the plane $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$, and
$(x_2,y_2)$, the area of the triangle determined by them is
given by the following formula:

$$A=\frac12\begin{vmatrix}x_0&y_0&1\\x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\end{vmatrix},$$

where the vertical bars represent the determinant.  If you
don't know what a determinant is, it doesn't matter too much;
the value of the expression above is:

$$\frac12(x_1 y_2 - y_1 x_2 -x_0 y_2 + y_0 x_2 + x_0 y_1 - y_0 x_1)$$

The amazing thing is that $A$ is positive if the three points are
taken in a counter-clockwise orientation, and negative otherwise.

To be inside a rectangle (or any convex body), as you trace
around in a clockwise direction from $p_1$ to $p_2$ to $p_3$ to $p_4$ and
back to $p_1$, the "areas" of triangles $p_1 p_2 p$, $p_2 p_3 p$, $p_3 p_4 p$,
and $p_4 p_1 p$ must all be positive.  If you don't know the orientation of your rectangle, then they must either all be positive or all be negative.

(I found the above method from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122124153/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54386.html))

How do I prove that the above is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting any row in a matrix from the other rows does not affect the determinant of the matrix, so
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{array}{c c c}x_0&y_0&1\\x_1-x_0&y_1-y_0&0\\x_2-x_0&y_2-y_0&0\end{array}\right|
$$
which, when expanded on the right column, does not depend on the top-left or the top-center elements, therefore
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{array}{c c c}0&0&1\\x_1-x_0&y_1-y_0&0\\x_2-x_0&y_2-y_0&0\end{array}\right|
$$
Setting $P_k=(x_k,y_k,0)$, $A=\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{P_0P_1}\times\overrightarrow{P_0P_2}\cdot(0,0,1)$, which is the directed area of the triangle with $\overrightarrow{P_0P_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{P_0P_2}$ as sides projected onto the plane perpendicular to $(0,0,1)$, which is the plane in which $\overrightarrow{P_0P_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{P_0P_2}$ lies.

Taking the smallest angle, if $\overrightarrow{P_0P_2}$ is counter-clockwise from $\overrightarrow{P_0P_1}$, then $A>0$; if $\overrightarrow{P_0P_2}$ is clockwise from $\overrightarrow{P_0P_1}$, then $A<0$.  Another way of looking at this is if $P_0$ is to the left of $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}$, then $A>0$; if $P_0$ is to the right of $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}$, then $A<0$.

Answer (score 6):

The test you describe checks that $p$ is to the left of every edge of the polygon and so lies in the intersection of the corresponding half-planes, which is the polygon itself.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to prove - how do i show that p lies to the left of every edge of the polygon ? Pls bear with me if its obvious - but I'm not getting it !!

Comment: @shan23, I assumed that this was clear: "if the determinant is positive if the three points are taken in a counter-clockwise orientation". If it is not, consider the simple case of one point being the origin, the other being $(1,0)$ and the third being $(x,y)$ and compute the determinant. This is indeed the general situation because the sign of the determinant is invariant by rotation and (positive) scaling.

Comment: @lhf I'm sure you didn't intend it in this way, but the phrase "I assumed that this was clear" can be interpreted as an insult, particularly in a text-only environment.

Comment: @Austin, I meant *no* insult. I've just expressed myself badly. What I meant what that I assumed that the OP was clear about that statement. (Or am I making it worse now?)